# VSTS private agent VSBuild

Tags: azure-pipelines, u-sql, azure-analysis-services

I have a solution with analysis service project and USQL project. I have VS2015 community installed on my machine. The solution builds perfect on my machine. Next I want to configure VSTS CI for my solution. I tried using the hosted agent but that is complaining that it cannot find assemblies as below:

1. > Cannot build obj\x86\Development\Model.asdatabase. Reason: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
2. > Error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.CompilerTask.USqlCompilerTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.CompilerTask. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.VsExtension.CompilerTask' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

I believed this could be due to the fact that hosted agent didn't have the utilities/configurations to build analysis service and usql projects.
So I decided to use my machine as a private VSTS agent to build the projects since it has all tools installed and is successfully building the solution from within Visual Studio.
However even after using my machine as the build agent it is showing the same error. I am using VSBuild.

So my question:

a. Why VSBuild doesn't ensure a good build when run on a private machine that can otherwise build a project from the installed VS2015 instance?
The machine environment is already supposed to be setup with all required tools/libraries and configuration hence these should be no problem.

b. If the above is not working then generally how to configure a private agent to handle cases which are not supported by the out of the box hosted agent?

c. Any advice on way to fix these errors when using VSBuild?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please trouble shooting the issue with below steps:

1. Build your project in VS 2015 on your local machine to make sure it can build successfully.
2. Make sure you are using the private agent configured on the machine for VSTS build. You can double check by reviewing the build log, and check the local path is where you configured your private agent.
3. In Visual Studio Build task, please make sure you are using the **visual studio version** is VS 2015.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for delay as I was badly stuck. Thanks I checked the details and they are setup correctly as you mention. The fact is all projects are building ok except for analysis service project and usql project. Since I am using VSBuild instead of MSBuild on my private agent which also as Visual Studio loaded I was expecting VSBuild to trigger Visual Studio build internally - so a successful build on Visual Studio should ensure a successful build using VSBuild. But it is not so. What is the value for VSBuild over MSBuild? Is it not required to have Visual Studio on build machine when using VSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that currently the usqlproj can only be built within the VisualStudio environment.  Standalone MSBuild is not yet supported.

Before we have a workable solution in the future, the only option here is to use the U-SQL SDK to build the U-SQL script directly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-sdk

Thanks a lot,
Yu Dong

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was testing that out. Sorry I am new to USQL and had a query maybe a bit naive. When I build the USQL query I see that the code behind gets compiled to dll and registered into local data lake catalog set for the environment. What exactly happens during this build? In our case we are not using backend C# code, only plain USQL script as procedures. We have developed powershell script that will be called during the release pipeline to deploy the script to destination catalog as procedures.In such case is there any value for a separate build step for the script?

Comment: Code behind c# code is only built when you have a "class" string in the code behind source file.   Temporary assembly registration and then deletion are used so it shouldn't leave traces in the local metadata storage when the job run succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry for delay in acknowledgement as I was a bit busy with other deliverables... A couple of questions - a) Is there anyway to build multiple usql files at one shot? I find that the -script argument takes one file at a time. b) Again back to original question, since I am using VSBuild instead of MSBuild I was expecting the build to be successful as it would use the same environment as the Visual Studio setup on the machine for the build. For VSTS private agents doesn't VSBuild underneath use the same environment as the Visual Studio environment on build machine?